# Returning a date cell if a sum a range of a row is equal to something

Tags: excel

I have a table that could go infinitely long, that has three categories per date. I need to figure out a way to have a cell return its date the earliest it reaches a numerical threshold (six in this case, or anything greater than five).

So with my specific workbook I’m working on ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfXBP.png)), column AM through CH could go on forever. I would like to figure out a function to have 6th IV (Column AL) be the date (Row 1) the cumulative 6th ‘IV’ took place. So for the 6th row AL6 would be 3/17/14, because the sum of each ‘IV’ (or column with a 3 in Row 3) hits 6 on cell BD6. One reason this is throwing me off is that I can’t just use countifs, so for example, Row 8, there are 2 ‘IV's on 2/3/14 (cell AO8), so the 6th ‘IV’ is on 3/3/14 (the 6th one being in cell BA8).
Does this make sense to anyone? Any ideas, thoughts, comments, concerns?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Solution**

```
Public Function fn_FindDate(ByVal SearchRange As Range)

    Dim Total As Integer

    Total = 0

    For Each Cell In SearchRange
      If Not IsNull(Cell.Value) Then
        Total = Total + Cell.Value
      End If

      If Total >= 6 Then
        Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        fn_FindDate = Range(Chr(64 + Cell.Column) & 1).Value
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next Cell

    fn_FindDate = ""

End Function
```

In Column A, you put the formula **=fn_FindDate(AM2:CH2)** and you should be good!  Feel free to remove the **Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3** if you don't want the 6th IV to turn red.

It's also set up to recognise when it PASSES 6.  If you have a 1, a 1 and a 5 in a row, the 5 will trigger, even though it technically skips from 2 to 7.  Also, it will return a blank value if the '6' threshold hasn't been met in a row, so you can just copy-down and it won't look sloppy.

Hope this helps!